# RuntimeBinderException: Convert type System.Threading.Tasks.Task<object> to string

Tags: type-conversion

I do an example with signalR. But it doesn't function because of one mistake.
The one mistake (**can not convert type system.threading.tasks.task< object> to string**) is in this line:

```
 return context.Clients.All.RecieveNotification(simple);
```

It is at the bottom of the code you can see below.

Below you see the method I wrote. There I do a connection with the database and get the content with a command/query.
Then a few checks and also SqlDependency.

```
public string SendNotifications()

    {

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))

        {

            string query = "SELECT  eintrag FROM [dbo].[simple_column]";

            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))

            {                  

                command.Notification = null;                

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);

                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)

                    connection.Open();                

                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                dt.Load(reader);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)

                {

                    simple = dt.Rows[0]["eintrag"].ToString();

                }

            }  

        }
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();

        return context.Clients.All.RecieveNotification(simple);
    }
```

And here I use the function:

```
var notifications = $.connection.notificationHub;
notifications.client.recieveNotification = function (simple) {

        // Add the message to the page.

        $('#dbMessage').text(simple);

    };
```

I hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: This all will function. Important is that you enter a query in the database: ALTER DATABASE name SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE. Also important is the CONNECTION STRING in web.config file which you use for Hub class.

Comment: I found the solution now: instead of PUBLIC STRING... I wrote PUBLIC TASK<OBJECT>